# Symfony 3 form assigns error to the FormType instead of the actual field

Tags: forms, validation, doctrine-orm, symfony, assert

I created a form in Symfony with this setup:

```
#\src\AppBundle\Entity\Order.php

class Order
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $orderID
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $orderID;

    /**
     * @var string $email
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;

    ...
```

In my form type:

```
# \src\AppBundle\Form\OrderType.php

class OrderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('order_id', TextType::class, [
                    'label' => 'index.order_id',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'index.order_id.placeholder'
                    )
                ])
                ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                    'label' => 'index.email',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'index.email.placeholder'
                    )
                ]);
        }

        ...
```

So if I submit the form with empty fields, Symfony detects both errors but the order ID error is assigned to the Class instead of the actual field.

Any ideas?

[image: Symfony Profiler]

**Update**

I renamed `protected $orderID;` to `protected $orderid;` and the problem is fixed! So why this happened? Is there any reserved names when it comes to the use of ID in the property name?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have this because that's what you specified in buildForm:

```
/**
  * @var string $order_id
  *
  * @ORM\Column(type="string")
  * @Assert\NotBlank()
  */
protected $order_id;
```

Can you try it?

Comment: This is related to how doctrine generates/parses entity properties.. Also we should use camelCase, not underscores, for variable, function and method names, arguments, according to Symfony best practices see [Naming Conventions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#naming-conventions)